# Swift window hierarchy error when I try to login or sign up in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, window

I have question about window hierarchy. When I try to login or sign up and open the home page of app, I can't present other pages console error give that:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

But when I re-open my app with same user everything working correctly. Here the code which is after create user process:

```
    func createUser(withEmail email: String, password: String, username: String) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to sign user up with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }

        let values = ["E-mail": email, "Kullanıcı Adı": username]

        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to update database values with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let homeController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
            self.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })

    }

}
```

here the function which call top function:

```
    @objc func handleSignUp() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }

    createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, username: username)
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: @mmr118 I have a button to sign up and this function call under that button function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your rootViewController is presenting another ViewController.
You can try :

```
if let presentedVC = self.presentedViewController {
    presentedVC.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
} else {
    self.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where are you add sign up button ??